# Javascript only runs one

Tags: javascript

I have a problem
where

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $("# btn"). click (function () {
         $ ("# canshow"). fadeToggle ("slow");
    });
 });
```

and

```
<a id="btn"> Button </ a>
<div id="canshow"> 1 </ div>
<div id="canshow"> 2 </ div>
<div id="canshow"> 3 </ div>
```

why that function only

```
<div id="canshow"> 1 </ div>
```

while others do not.
I want

```
<div id="canshow"> 2 </ div>
<div id="canshow"> 3 </ div>
```

also works. please Helpme.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes instead

Comment: having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML and breaks any garauntee of javascript working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `class`. Ids must be unique..

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $("#btn").click(function() {
         $(".canshow").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
 });
```

and

```
<a id="btn"> Button </a>
<div class="canshow"> 1 </div>
<div class="canshow"> 2 </div>
<div class="canshow"> 3 </div>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/szF33/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a class instead of an ID. Try this:

```
$ (".canshow"). fadeToggle ("slow");
```

With this HTML:

```
 <div class="canshow"> 1 </ div>
 <div class="canshow"> 2 </ div>
 <div class="canshow"> 3 </ div>
```

---

See [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for more information. In particular:

> `id = name [CS]`
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.
>
> `class = cdata-list [CS]`
>
> This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

Comment: waww.....
thank you for your help.
It runs perfectly. thank you very much, I'll call you Master. Thank you very much

Comment: @KarebetConnec - No problem, just glad to help.